# Constructor can only be defined outside class

Tags: c++, oop

In the following code, the constructor can only be defined outside the class, or compiler will give errors.

```
class Student;
class Teacher 
{
private:
    int num;
    string name;
    string sex;
    string title;
public:
    Teacher(Student &s) {
        num=s.num ;
        name=s.name ;
        sex=s.sex ;
    }
    void display();
};

class Student
{
public:
    int num;
    string name;  
    string sex;
    float grade;
    friend Teacher;
    void set_student();
};

void Teacher::display()
{
    cout<<num<<" "<<name<<" "<<sex<<endl;
} 


void Student::set_student() 
{ 
    cin>>num>>name>>sex>>grade;
} 


int main()
{
    Student s1;
    s1.set_student() ;
    Teacher t1(s1);  
    t1.display() ;
    return 0;
}
```

It didn't compile, but if I move the definition of the constructor outside the class, it compiles:

```
class Teacher
{
public:
Teacher(Student &s);
...
};

Teacher::Teacher(Student &s)
{
    num=s.num ;
    name=s.name ;
    sex=s.sex ;
}
```

The error is:

```
floyd.cpp: In constructor 'Teacher::Teacher(Student&)':
floyd.cpp:37:8: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Student'
   num=s.num ;
        ^
floyd.cpp:27:7: error: forward declaration of 'class Student'
 class Student;
       ^
floyd.cpp:38:9: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Student'
   name=s.name ;
         ^
floyd.cpp:27:7: error: forward declaration of 'class Student'
 class Student;
       ^
floyd.cpp:39:8: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Student'
   sex=s.sex ;
        ^
floyd.cpp:27:7: error: forward declaration of 'class Student'
 class Student;
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: you can not use class variable by just forwarding the class.

Comment: A Student shouldn't consider a teacher a friend, sorry :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to be able to compile this declaration

```
Teacher(Student &s);
```

the compiler needs to know about class `Student` only that it exists. Forward declaration

```
class Student;
```

successfully fulfills this requirement: it tells the compiler that there is going to be a definition of class `Student` at some later point. However, in order to be able to compile this code

```
Teacher(Student &s) {
    num=s.num ;
    ...
}
```

the compiler needs to know the content of the `Student` class as well. Specifically, it needs to know that `Student` has member variable `num`. This is not possible until the point of your program where `Student` class is fully defined.

There are two ways of addressing this issue:

- You already discovered the first one - move constructor definition out of the class, or
- Switch the order of declarations, and forward-declare `Teacher` - this is possible because `Student`'s code does not depend on `Teacher`'s definition.

Comment: Thank you, that is very kind of you.

Answer (score 2):

This is not related to in-class vs. out-of-class at all. It's all the matter of whether the type `Student` is complete (= fully defined) when you use it.

You'll get the exact same error if you move the constructor of the definition of `Teacher`, but place it above the definition of `Student`.

Since the `Teacher` constructor accesses member variables of `Student`, it needs to see the full definition of `Student`. Just switch the order of the class definitions.

Comment: I have tried move the constructor of the definition of `Teacher`, it really got the same error, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the compiler explains it in detail:

```
floyd.cpp: In constructor 'Teacher::Teacher(Student&)':
floyd.cpp:37:8: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Student'
   num=s.num ;
```

On the line 37 the class `Student` is incomplete (since by that line you only forwardly declared it), and accessing its members is prohibited.

This may be fixed by placing the code of `Student` class above the code of `Teacher` class:

```
class Teacher; // Forward declaration, for the 'friend' line
class Student {..}; // All the code you now have in the Student class
class Teacher {..}; // All the code of Teacher class
```

Comment: Upvoted for explaining the meaning of the compiler error